# Using Webview.findAll()

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a problem using WebView in Android. When I search in a Webview with `Webview.findAll(String)` method it search all the occurrences but it does`t give me the integer with the number of results. Any ideas on whats going wrong? It exists an alternative to search all the occurrences and have total number of occurrences in a Webview?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it with a [WebView.FindListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.FindListener.html).The Method `onFindResultReceived` has the parameter `numberOfMatches`.